# (node .) command: "throw new errors.ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE('listener', 'Function', listener);"

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've been trying to make my bot go live on Discord, but I got this error and don't know how to fix it:

[image: error]

Also, here is the "package.json" file:

```
{
  "name": "botName",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "raidBot.js",
  "scripts": {
    "text": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "uwu || dm 2 partner#7245 & lottie#8696",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^11.4.2"
  },
  "description": ""
}
```

"botName.js" file:

```
const discord = require('discord.js');

var client = new discord.Client();

const token = "instertedTokenHere";

client.on ("ready", () => {
    console.log("the bot is ready...");

    client.user.setGame ("prefix is $");
});

const prefix = "$";
client.on ("message"), (message) => {

    if (message.author.bot) return;

    if (message.content.startsWith (prefix + "bot")) {
        message.reply ('Running...');
    }

};
```

**NOTE:** This is what I did that resulted in the error:

```
cd D:\bot004
npm install
npm install --save discord.js
node .
```

Everything seems fine though. I have the `node_modules` folder and `package.json`, `package-lock.json`, and `botName.js` files.

Comment: Show what did you do at line 14 of raiBot.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Your code
const discord = require('discord.js');

var client = new discord.Client();

const token = "instertedTokenHere";

client.on ("ready", () => {
    console.log("the bot is ready...");

    client.user.setGame ("prefix is $");
});

const prefix = "$";
client.on ("message"), (message) => {

    if (message.author.bot) return;

    if (message.content.startsWith (prefix + "bot")) {
        message.reply ('Running...');
    }

};
```

This looks a little suspect. You are not passing in the callback function to the `.on()` method below. That's where your error is coming from.

```
client.on ("message"), (message) => {

    if (message.author.bot) return;

    if (message.content.startsWith (prefix + "bot")) {
        message.reply ('Running...');
    }

};
```

Try refactoring to this:

```
client.on ("message", (message) => {

    if (message.author.bot) return;

    if (message.content.startsWith (prefix + "bot")) {
        message.reply ('Running...');
    }

});
```

I am able to reproduce the error when I run your code as is. The error subsides when I fix the code.

Comment: Thanks! It worked now... But there's another problem: When i type "node ." nothig happens... Why?

Comment: @familyfriendlycontent I'm not familiar with discord, so I'm not sure what the script is supposed to do.

Comment: @familyfriendlycontent It looks like the final step you need to call to get it start listening for messages is to call `client.login(<your bot token here>)`.  See in their example: https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord.js

Comment: @familyfriendlycontent I was able to get a discord server running, add my bot to the server, and set up my node client to respond with a basic message following the docs. Hope you have some luck with it! I appreciate you showing this to me. :)

Answer (score 0):

Place your client variable under the token. I had the same error when I made my discord bot.

Comment: Same error, it also says: "'token' is declared but the variable is never read."